# "TemplateDoesNotExist at / home1.html"whereas {%load static%} creating 'UNWANTED TOKEN ' error in <DOCTYPE html>

Tags: python, html, django, django-staticfiles

I am getting error in my HTML file'home.html' when I add {% load static %} command at the first row,
it shows an error as **UNWANTED TOKEN** ON 
I am new to the pyhton and learning from online classes , whenever i enter load static static file an error comes out on doctype html with ziggly red line ,I dont know how to solve it and when i run server it gic=ves me this :-

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home1.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home1.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\admin\\PycharmProjects\\magezine\\telusko',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**MY HTML file error**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Travello</title>
```

**settings**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),


]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

**MY project name is telesko and installed app name is travello**

Comment: It has nothing to do with the template, etc. itself, you simply did specify a template path that does not exists. Please post the file tree (including the template) and the view that aims to render that template.

Comment: You can also check `DIRS` settings according to this documentation link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#configuration Feel free to add directories to `DIRS` array.

Comment: The "ziggly red line" is because your text editor doesn't understand the Django template syntax, which is unrelated to your error. As @DenizKaplan said, check your templates configuration in `settings.py`

Comment: How to get over from  ziggly line @hedgie

Comment: That depends on the text editor that you are using. You will have to configure syntax highlighting to both accept HTML and Django syntax.

Comment: the error was due to the missing of jinja extension.